# What are the deep learning books covering stochastic differential equations only?

Tags: machine-learning, python, references, differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

I want to solve a simple Stochastic Differential Equation say $$dY=Y^2 dt+\sigma Y^2 dW$$ and then make future predictions.

I am conversant with MATLAB and LSTMs in python. Is there a book that can help me find a machine learning code that can assist me to make such prediction?

Comment: why would you need ML to solve this equation?

Comment: I have already figured out the way of applying the machine learning my boss. I have the only effect is that of estimating \sigma. Thanks my boss. Then I had little understanding of machine learning. If you know any book covering PINN you can recommend to help me increase understanding.